# "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference"

Tags: android-fragments

Unable to load application and it displays null pointer error.And error is like "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference"

I already written same code in my another activity, over there it is working but here its not working.I want to display date picker on textview click.

Here is my java class code:

```
public class AdminProfileActivity extends Fragment {

DatePickerDialog picker;

private String date;
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_calendar, container, false);
    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final TextView txtDate=(TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.txtBirtday);
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    date = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    txtDate.setText(date);
    txtDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            // date picker dialog
            picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                        }
                    }, year, month, day);
            picker.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
            picker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
            picker.show();
        }
    });


    return rootview;
}
}
```

Here is .XML file code:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AdminProfileActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtInputName"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:textColorHint="#0E0D0D">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:hint="Enter Your Name"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Birthdate"
        android:textColor="#0E0D0D"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtBirtday"
        android:focusable="false"
        />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gender"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mrname_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rbtnMale"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Male"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rbtnFemale"
        android:text="Female"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</RadioGroup>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtInputAddress"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:textColorHint="#0E0D0D">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
        android:hint="Enter Your Address"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/txtInputCity"
app:errorEnabled="true"
android:textColorHint="#0E0D0D">
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtCity"
    android:hint="City"
    android:inputType="text" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtInputState"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:textColorHint="#0E0D0D">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtState"
        android:hint="State"
        android:inputType="text" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtInputCountry"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:textColorHint="#0E0D0D">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtCountry"
        android:hint="Country"
        android:inputType="text" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtInputPhone"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:textColorHint="#0E0D0D">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        android:inputType="textPhonetic" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtInputEmail"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:textColorHint="#0E0D0D">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save Profile"
    android:background="#1D77D6"
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```